# Changing Multiple DB Fields to Lower Case

Tags: mysql, sql

With phpMyAdmin, I can use the following SQL to change all values in the table.field mytable.Site to lower case...

```
UPDATE my_table SET Site=LOWER(Site)
```

I have a zillion tables that have this same field, and I'd like to change all of them to lower case. Is there a SQL command that will do that - change EVERY field named Site in every table to lower case (preferably without having to list every table that has that field)?

Answer (score 0):

Not EXACTLY what you want,but pretty close.Tested on my machine.
First create a procedure

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN tbl CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ',tbl,' SET Site=LOWER(Site)' );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

And for finding tables with a certain column name:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('Site')
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDB';
```

For calling the procedure

```
CALL test('tableName')
```

Comment: Wow, cool; I didn't know you can string scripts together in phpMyAdmin like that. I'm getting an error, though - ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
STR: //
SQL: delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN tbl CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ',tbl,' SET Site=LOWER(Site)' );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;

But maybe I did it wrong; I assume I'm supposed to paste the entire script in and do the replacement in one procedure, right? Thanks.

Comment: Try a better client such as heidisql.Phpmyadmin raises my blood pressure.

Comment: LOL - Good to know there are better programs out there. ;)

Comment: I have no idea why it gives you that error,those queries should be run separately.It works for me..